# Is there a good commercially available serial port library

Tags: c#

I am running into issues using the Serial Port component available in .net 3.5 sp1.
It seems a number of people are facing the same issue.
Does anyone know of a good quality alternative to Microsoft's component?
 Thanks

Comment: It would help if you mentioned what problems you were having.  Otherwise another library with the same issues will get recomended

Comment: I second JardePar. The serial port interface in the BCL seems perfectly fine to me. I find it very unlikely that it's not stable/complete. Of course, you may be having vendor-specific issues, in which case you need to post more info.

Comment: There are many documented problems , including open and unresolved issues such as the component throwing uncatchable objectDisposed Exceptions ( a problem  that I am experiencing) . The component was virtually useless from after .net 2.0 to up until version 3.5 sp1.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/8a1825d2-c84b-4620-91e7-3934a4d47330

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/aa5280a4-b3aa-4e96-98d0-4e587892a68e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [alternative](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/showcase/SerialPortDotNet.aspx) on CodeProject.

Hope this helps!